# Make Oracle last_day function be compatible with H2 database

Tags: oracle, h2

I am writing integration testing and I want to test my sql queries by using a H2 database. In production these queries are running against an Oracle database.

I have to run this query

I have tries to use the compatibility mode

```
SELECT last_day(MY_CURRENT_DATE) from MY_TIME
```

by using the oracle compatibility mode `jdbc:h2:mem:default;MODE=Oracle;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1` but I receive this error:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Function "LAST_DAY" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT last_day(MY_CURRENT_DATE) from MY_TIME [90022-176]
```

It just seems that the compatibility mode does not cover the vendor-specific functions.

I have an idea how to solve this in testing. Just override the Oracle `last_day` function with a H2 user-defined function:

```
DROP ALIAS IF EXISTS last_day;

CREATE ALIAS last_day AS $$
String last_day(java.sql.Connection con, Date date) throws Exception {
        //get the last day of month
  }
}
$$;
```

But I am wondering if it is the best idea?
Is there a way to re-write the Oracle `LAST_DAY` function (that calculates the last day of month) in a way which is compatible with all other databases (including H2)?

Comment: Another good example on why using a different DBMS for testing then in production is not a good idea

Comment: I would use an in-memory database rather than the one I use in production. That is because I want my integration tests to run fast.

Comment: Fast doesn't buy you anything if the test is meaningless

Comment: I like how the [support link](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) on the H2 site points to Stack Overflow ;)  But I have to agree with @a_horse_with_no_name , if you can afford Oracle licenses for production, you should probably standup a basic Oracle dev/test instance.

Comment: Even if I use the dev/test instance, it will not be suitable for test automation. Those instances are shared between human users (developers, QA's) and the automated tests. What I would want to have is a specific/unique and fast environment for the automated tests. Question: even if I set up an Oracle database dedicated for automated tests, how would I make sure that no one from my team uses that database and corrupts test data in the middle of automated test runs?

Comment: Well, in my company anyway, we have a dev environment, a UAT (User Acceptance Test) environment, and the Production environments.  Dev can be modified by developers, but UAT environment has strictly controlled releases (you can think of it as a dry run for a Production release).  UAT is where applications are tested internally (by QA dept not dev testing).  Once all UAT tests pass, we can approve for Production release.

Comment: Yes, I understand, most of the companies have the same setup (or else should strive for this setup). What I would ideally think is best is to have a dedicated UAT environment (an additional one) that would be used to run acceptance testing in isolation with the other UAT environments. No one should touch that environment, only the automated acceptance tests should have the rights to run there. Regarding the automated integration tests you can use an in-memory database in order to mock the database server component, and you can run them in the Dev environments.

Comment: I agree with both. Sometimes we need to test it the query returns the data specified in the functional requirements. This needs to be tested in unit tests. And is best to automate in a memory based DB like H2.
But for user acceptance test that combines all requirements as well as functionality and performance, it needs to be done on a prod like database.
Here comes the help of tools like hibernate, that generates the query for you according to the DB system you use under the hood.
But if you want to write your own queries for performance, then hibernate is not the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear for me that for acceptance/system tests you should use a database very similar to the one in production.

For the integration and unit testing you can mock the database server component entirely.