# Make oracle last_day function compatible between oracle and h2

Tags: java, oracle, h2

I have a sql Query in a java project. It has to be executed in oracle and h2 depending on the client and it's DBMS election.

It has to return values where sent_date is Month minus one (previous month registries)

```sql
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE SENT_DATE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'mm'),-1) 
AND LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'mm'),-1)) ORDER BY ELAPSED_TIME DESC
```

Problem is, LAST_DAY function is a Oracle specific function, which is not present in H2, and H2 date managing sometimes doesn't work in Oracle, but I need it fully compatible. There is a previous question [Make Oracle last_day function be compatible with H2 database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41377051/make-oracle-last-day-function-be-compatible-with-h2-database) but answers focus on a poorly tested system, rather than in a correct solution.

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be happier with:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE SENT_DATE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'mm'),-1) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE,'mm') - 1
ORDER BY ELAPSED_TIME DESC
```

Showing that they evaluate to the same value:

```
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'mm'),-1) as orig_start,
  LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'mm'),-1)) as orig_end,
  TRUNC(SYSDATE,'mm') - 1 as new_end
FROM dual;

ORIG_START          ORIG_END            NEW_END            
------------------- ------------------- -------------------
2019-08-01 00:00:00 2019-08-31 00:00:00 2019-08-31 00:00:00
```

But remember that `between` is inclusive, so if your `sent_date` has non-midnight times that would exclude anything from 2019-08-31 00:00:01 to 2019-08-31 23:59:59.

It's safer to do:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE SENT_DATE >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'mm'),-1)
AND SENT_DATE < TRUNC(SYSDATE,'mm')
ORDER BY ELAPSED_TIME DESC
```

which will include everything on or after 2019-08-01 00:00:00, and up to (but excluding) 2019-09-01 00:00:00 - so that missing day will not be present.

Or if it doesn't recognise `add_months` either perhaps:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE SENT_DATE >= TRUNC(SYSDATE,'mm') - INTERVAL '1' MONTH
AND SENT_DATE < TRUNC(SYSDATE,'mm')
ORDER BY ELAPSED_TIME DESC
```

(I am not able to test that any of these actually work in H2... *8-)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'mm'),-1))
```

can be simplified to

```sql
TRUNC(SYSDATE,'mm') - 1
```

without `LAST_DAY` function, but H2 also does not support non-standard `TRUNC` with 'mm' argument.

So you need to avoid it too. Such query will be compatible with both databases (however, you need a recent version of H2, such as 1.4.199, for example):

```sql
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE SENT_DATE BETWEEN
    CURRENT_DATE - (EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE) - 1) - INTERVAL '1' MONTH
AND
    CURRENT_DATE - EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE)
ORDER BY ELAPSED_TIME DESC
```

Please note that this query is not standard, I intentionally used Oracle-style date arithmetic to simplify the query, it is supported by H2. You can also use  non-standard `ADD_MONTH` here, if you wish.

If you'll need to use standard syntax only for compatibility with more databases, you can avoid Oracle/H2-style arithmetic:

```sql
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE SENT_DATE BETWEEN
    CURRENT_DATE - (EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE) - 1) * INTERVAL '1' DAY - INTERVAL '1' MONTH
AND
    CURRENT_DATE - EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE) * INTERVAL '1' DAY
ORDER BY ELAPSED_TIME DESC
```

Please also note that Oracle, unlike other databases, doesn't have the normal `DATE` data type, its `DATE` type may have time (H2 can emulate this deviation in Oracle compatibility mode). So all these queries with 'BETWEEN', including your initial Oracle-only query will work properly only if you ensure that your dates are all at `00:00:00`. If your dates contain also time part you need to use a couple of comparison operators:

```sql
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE SENT_DATE >=
    CURRENT_DATE - (EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE) - 1) - INTERVAL '1' MONTH
AND SENT_DATE <
    CURRENT_DATE - (EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE) - 1)
ORDER BY ELAPSED_TIME DESC
```

(The Oracle/H2 arithmetic was used here too, for other databases multiplication to `INTERVAL '1' DAY` can be necessary.)